# Multiple jQuery Datatables on same page

Tags: jquery, css, datatables

I have two jQuery datatables on the same ascx page.  I'm trying to insert a hyperlink into the toolbar div, which calls a link in the code behind, after the table has been rendered.  Here's the code:

```
           var SDFtable = $('#tblSDF').dataTable(
            {
                "scrollY": "300px",
                "scrollX": true,
                "scrollCollapse": true,
                "paging": false,
                "autowidth": true,

                dom: '<"toolbar"><"filterPad"f>rti<"floatRight"B><"clear">',

                //all available button options
                //'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'

                buttons: {
                    buttons: [
                        { extend: 'excel', text: 'Download this grid in Excel', exportOption: { page: 'current' }, footer: true }
                    ]
                }

            });

          $("div.toolbar").html('<h2><a id="aSDFExport" title="Click here to download full report" OnServerClick="ExportFundingSummaryToExcel"  runat="server">SDF Pool</a></h2>');
```

The problem is that I have two of these blocks of code, one for each table, and when the second $("div.toolbar") line runs, it adds that link to both datatables.  How can I reference that specific to the table that is being drawn?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do both of your tables have an ID of `#tblSDF`?

Comment: Maybe this might help  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7827986/multiple-datatables-on-the-same-page-with-different-ajax-sources

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$("#tblSDF_wrapper div.toolbar").html('<h2><a id="aSDFExport" title="Click here to download full report" OnServerClick="ExportFundingSummaryToExcel"  runat="server">SDF Pool</a></h2>');
```

Comment: Got it, still picking up on jQuery element traversal, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('#tblSDF').find("div.toolbar").html('<h2><a id="aSDFExport" title="Click here to download full report" OnServerClick="ExportFundingSummaryToExcel"  runat="server">SDF Pool</a></h2>');
```